# SSRS does not show the image on the report by Embeded type

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

In SSRS I have the follwoing setting for an Image on a report:

```
MIME Type= Image/jpeg
Source=Embeded
Value= points to the file
```

when I generate the report from CRM the report does not show the image. It generates a long URL with ImageID, SessionID and so on. So it seems it cannt find the image. Can we put the base64 and put it in SRC in IMG tag directly? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: it should show the image, have you added the image to the report--embedded it first ?

Answer (score 0):

For my 20111 On-Prem, I have a CRM SSRS report that is pulling JPG pictures that are "attachments" in CRM.  We set the image source to the Base64 "Body" field on Annotation.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is we have created the SSRS on report server and puuling the report via a workflow and set the body of email the result which come from the SSRS. Not sure if your way is ok for this scenario?

Comment: Hmm, turning the output of an SSRS into the body of an email...that is entirely different.  In that case, you probably need a "public access URL" to your image and just use <img src=""> in the email. I'm not sure I would use SSRS for that...I have been using unsent Email records as "templates" for my emails.  I'd love to hear how you solve it.

Comment: So I did it in this way: Before send the rendered html to the workflow I replaced the whole image with the embeded image containing the base64 of the image. I t was not the solution but for this scenario it works fine.